# How do you use the ExplorerEvents_10_CloseEventHandler?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I want to run some code when the InLineResponse has closed. For example if the user was to use the addin to to pop out a reply for some code to get called when the inlineresponse closes.

I have looked found the following documentation explaining features which i believe would do the job.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.inlineresponseclose
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.explorerevents_10_closeeventhandler?view=outlook-pia
However I am still unsure how to execute this in code.

Comment: What are you having problems with? Setting the InlineResponseClose event handler? What have you tried?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I am just not sure how to create the event handler. I assume it is something similar to creating an event handler for the send function (Application.ItemSend += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);)

Comment: Yes, it is not any different. Are you running into a particular problem when doing that?

Comment: I am just not sure of the exact syntax to use. As in what should Application.ItemSend be changed to. I am guessing the correct syntax is like this "(Unknown) += new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_CloseEventHandler(ExplorerObject_Quit);"

Comment: This got it to work
"Outlook.Explorer myExplorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer();
((Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_Event)myExplorer).InlineResponseClose+= new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_InlineResponseCloseEventHandler(Explorer_InlineResponseClose);"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Outlook.Explorer myExplorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer();
((Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_Event)myExplorer).InlineResponseClose+= new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_InlineResponseCloseEventHandler(Explorer_InlineResponseClose);

void Explorer_InlineResponseClose(){ // Code to run here}
```